# Weighted union rule

Tags: data-structures, union-find

Can someone check with me if I'm using the rule right in the last step (7)?

UPDATE:

**Numbers inside the parentheses are the number of elements (weight(?)) of each set that takes part in the Union.** Uppercase letters are names of sets.

As I understand this: we are using as our rank the number of elements? This is getting confusing, each one is using different terms for the same stuff.

We have Unions:

1. U(1,2,A)
2. U(3,4,B)
3. U(A,B,C)
4. U(5,6,D)
5. U(7,8,E)
6. U(D,C,F)
7. U(E,F,G)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Step 7 (and the others) looks correct, but step 6 doesn't.

In step 6, 4 should be the root, as that's the bigger tree.

Comment: 1+2+3+4=10 and 5+6=11 , shouldn't 6 be the root in step 6? (cause of the weight)

Comment: I've never seen a union-find algorithm that uses the nodes' values as the weight - this won't make a whole lot of sense either, as the nodes' values don't really correspond to the running time of operations. It usually uses the height / depth of the tree.

Comment: I updated my problem as you instructed, I think it's correct now(?).

Comment: Sorry, there is a catch in the problem I did an edit. These things are very tricky!

Answer (score 0):

```
void combine(int x,int y)
{
    int xroot=find(x),yroot=find(y);
    if(rank[xroot]<rank[yroot]) 
        parent[xroot]=yroot;
    else if(rank[xroot]>rank[yroot]) 
    parent[yroot]=xroot;
    else 
    {///rank of both is equal..
        parent[yroot]=xroot;
        rank[xroot]++;
    }
}
```

Using rank, you see the `size of set`, not sum of vertices, so step `6` is wrong.

**But why the `size`?**
Because if we make root of bigger set the root of smaller set , we need to `update` parents of smaller number of nodes.

For the best explanation, I would recommend [CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844).

Hope it helps you!